# Al actualizar el password hash varía la clave... la cambia

Tags: php, update, hash

Tengo un usuario coach que puede cambiar la clave de sus alumnos, cuando se realiza este cambio de clave, modifica la DB pero la clave no funciona... hay alguna diferencia entre el INSERT y el UPDATE?

```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    
   $query = " UPDATE usuarios SET password = '$passwordHash' WHERE id = $id";
   $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    
   if ($resultado) {
        header('Location: entrenador.php');
    }
    }
```

Este es el formulario de donde vienen los datos...

```
<form class="register-form2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="password">Nuevo Password</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Nuevo Password" required autocomplete="off" minlength="8">
     <span class="hint alert-success">Escribe un Password, con 8 caracteres </span>
     <input type="submit" value="Cambia Password" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
</form>
```

Este es el mismo script con el que se creo el usuario por primera vez, y al crearle el password si funciona.

Algún experto que por favor me oriente... desde ya gracias.

Comment: Nota. Los hash creados con `password_hash` siempre serán distintos, aunque la clave sea igual, por lo tanto no se puede hacer una comparación simple. Debes usar [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) para comparar la entrada del usuario contra el registro de la BD.

Comment: Hola. En tu código no se ve dónde defines el valor de `$password`. Y asumes que la clave es actualizada, pero tampoco se ve en el código nada que lo confirme. ¿Cómo sabes que se actualizó la clave? Quizá la has verificado en la base de datos, pero en el código, nada de nada. Aparte de verificar el no error de la ejecución de la consulta, deberías controlar el valor de `affected_rows` para notificar al usuario de que el UPDATE ocurrió con éxito o falló. Estás escribiendo un programa demasiado *optimista* y eso es un problema grave en programación, contrario a lo que se podría pensar.

Comment: Otra cosa más. ¿Por qué tienes esto en tu formulario: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?. Debes definirlo como multipart solamente si vas a enviar archivos adjuntos, cosa que no haces en ese formulario.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano... tienes toda la razón....  quite el `form-data` del enctype y defini `$password` como lo indica @OCHOA más adelante y funcionó...  Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

A simple vista y con el código exacto que muestras se ve que no inicializas la variable **$password**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $password = $_POST['password']; // Esto te hace falta
     $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    
   $query = " UPDATE usuarios SET password = '$passwordHash' WHERE id = $id";
   $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    
   if ($resultado) {
        header('Location: entrenador.php');
    }
    }
```

Ahora bien, yo te recomendaría usar funciones para esas tareas

```
class helpers{
   public function encryptPassword($pass){
      $hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, [15]);
      return $hash;
   }
}
$helpers = new helpers();

// Y así la llamas desde donde sea
$passwordHash = $helpers->encryptPassword($password);
```

Usando `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` con un coste bueno (como el que uso yo) te aseguras que los passwords quedaran encriptados de una mejor manera. El cost, son los ciclos de hash que le haces al string de entrada. Yo uso 15 ya que el default es 10.

Comment: Hola @OCHOA, muchas gracias por tu apoyo... efectivamente no había declarado el `$password`y  después de hacerlo funcionó.  También quite el `form-data` en el formulario....   GRACIAS

Comment: Gracias por lo de las funciones, las tendré muy en cuenta ... te cuento.

Comment: Esto no basta: `$password = $_POST['password'];`. Si no se postea un valor en `password`, vas a tener un *`Undefined index`*.  Es el típico error que yo llamo *programación optimista*, escribir código sin prever posibles errores **de lógica o de validación u otros**. Para evitar eso, podrías recoger el valor usando fusión de null (o un ternario combinado con `empty` en su defecto) y verificar si no es nulo. Algo así: **`$password = $_POST['password'] ?? null; if ($password) { //proceder } else { //No se posteó password, avisar al usuario de su error }`**

Comment: @ivanjaviergonzalezabello Y si la respuesta te ha servido, considera marcarla como aceptada, activando el símbolo de cotejo **✓** a la izquierda de la misma.

Comment: @A.Cedano como siempre tiene razón. Pero le diré que antes yo respondía más extendido, pero varios me decían que tenia que responder exactamente a lo que el user preguntaba. Además y que pasa si los datos no son del formato que se necesita? hay que sanitizarlos, parsearlos y/o verificarlos en base a nuestros criterios, en fin, por eso yo no me extiendo y respondo tal cual lo que piden. En mi caso por ejemplo, son mínimo 4 los filtros que aplico a la info de un form antes de procesarla, pero repito, no creo que sea lo mejor extenderme a eso, o por lo menos sin saber el nivel del que postea :-)

Comment: @OCHOA si lo tengo en validación de errores... `// autentica el usuario
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['cedula']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['password']);

    if (!$cedula){
        $errores[] = 'El documento es obligatorio'; 
    }
    if (!$password) {
        $errores[] = 'El Password es obligatorio'; 
    }`
Gracias..

Comment: Muy bien @ivanjaviergonzalezabello. Y a veces también los usuarios solo postean la parte del código que les da error. En fin, muchas veces me ha pasado que por suponer algo me sale peor jejej. Pero los consejos siempre son bienvenidos. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada... Salu2